Can't we model a probabilistic turing machine using deterministic turing machine?
I was trying to get my head around turing machine and I have such question.
Let's take a deterministic turing machine.
We know it has a transition function.
Now can't this transition function have following logic inside:

generate random number
if the generated random number is even move to state A else to state B

If the transition function can have such logic, does not that make it a probabilistic turing machine?
What are other features of a probabilistic turing machine which a deterministic turing machine can't have (and thus we needed a separate notion of a probabilistic turing machine) ?.

"Anyone who considers arithmetical methods of producing random digits is, of course, in a state of sin." (von Neumann)

A deterministic Turing Machine is a piece of mathematics. It has a mathematical definition. Different textbooks and different articles use slightly different definitions, but they are all very similar, and they all have in common that the transitions cannot have such logic inside.
The same thing is true for a nondeterministic Turing Machine.
Could you change one of these mathematical definitions such that it makes transitions pick their target state probabilistically? Yes, absolutely; in fact, people have already done so. Would the result be a probabilistic Turing Machine? Well, that's what they call it, but you could also call it a Squonk if you like. The name doesn't matter; what matters is the mathematics. But in any case, the result is no longer a deterministic or nondeterministic Turing Machine. It is a separate notion.
It is not meaningful to ask which features a deterministic Turing Machine can or cannot have. It has a definition, and the definition determines its features. If you change the definition to remove or add features, the result is no longer a deterministic Turing Machine.
